# My cursor is changed after "df"

Tags: neovim, cursor

I have the following to change my cursor from a block into an underline:

```
set guicursor=a:hor20-Cursor
```

Whenever I run `df` to delete a range, my cursor is changed back to a block.

I have to source my config to have it as an underscore again.

This behaviour seems to happen only with Neovim and not Vim itself.

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem with the config you gave. Have you tried to remove everything from your `init.conf` excepted `set guicursor=a:hor20-Cursor`? If it still happens I think you'll have to report a bug to neovim otherwise, please check [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841) to try to find what is causing the issue. You can edit your question with the details of what you'll find following the methodology of the question I linked.

Comment: @statox Thanks. Turns out if was a plugin named `clever-f` that was messing up my guicursor.